# Capturing a library's printf output from the caller in OCaml

Tags: dns, printf, ocaml, opam

I'm using ocaml-dns.

[Here](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-dns/blob/f3ac82b71efbd95bfda1c4acd44eb52061b42410/lwt/dns_resolver.ml#L42) you can see it do

```
 printf "retrying query for %d times\n%!" (4-count);
```

and it's cluttering my logs! I'm already handling failures, I don't care about that output and I want to silence it. How can I do that without forking and modifying the library itself? Can I buffer its output somehow?

Thanks

Comment: You are out of luck. Libraries should never output to standard file descriptors except if explicitely told so. I filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-dns/issues/36).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-like system you can redirect the standard output to "/dev/null". Something like this might work:

```
let nullout = open_out "/dev/null" in
Unix.dup2 (Unix.descr_of_out_channel nullout) Unix.stdout
```

Here's a session showing that it works (at least for me on OS X):

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# #load "unix.cma";;
# Sys.system "echo unwanted message";;
Error: Unbound value Sys.system
# Sys.command "echo unwanted message";;
unwanted message
- : int = 0
# let nullout = open_out "/dev/null" in
  Unix.dup2 (Unix.descr_of_out_channel nullout) Unix.stdout;;
Sys.command "echo unwanted message";;
Sys.command "echo error message >&2";;
error message
```

If you need to use standard output at other times, you have a worse problem. You can redirect stdout back to where it was before with some extra uses of `dup`, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use `dup`, but unfortunately I need to be able to write my own stuff to stdout, I just want to silence that noisy library. Daniel Bünzli commented on my question and then filed a bug on Github and the authors said they're going to fix it.

Comment: If you want to get very furiously active with `dup` I'm pretty sure you can make it work. But fixing the bug is vastly superior.

Comment: Yeah, I could redirect to null before every call to it and then back to the normal output right after. I might do that in the mean time if it doesn't affect performance too much.